# Drawing with Canvas in JavaFX

Tags: canvas, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

Imagine, you have a `canvas` instance

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
```

and I wanna draw some `pieces` with `GraphicsContext`

```
GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
```

This method has the functionality of creating `round pieces`, the `Color` of this part does not matter and in fact the method draws a `circle`, in which it needed some adjustment for the drawing to go according to the objective

```
public void drawRoundPiece(GraphicsContext gc) {
        gc.setFill(Color.BLUE);//text color
        gc.setStroke(Color.BLUE);//text color
        gc.fillOval(50, 50, 50, 50);
        gc.strokeOval(50, 50, 50, 50);
        gc.fill();
        gc.stroke();
    }
```

This method has the functionality of creating `square pieces` with `circle in middle`, the `Color` of this part does not matter and in fact the method draws a `square`, in which it needed some adjustment for the drawing to go according to the objective

```
public void drawSquarePiece(GraphicsContext gc) {
        gc.setFill(Color.YELLOW);//text color
        gc.setStroke(Color.YELLOW);//text color
        gc.fillRoundRect(100, 10, 50, 50, 10, 10);
        gc.fill();
        gc.stroke();
    }
```

and the objetive is draw the pieces like image in down

[image]

any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to take a look at `LinearGradient` fill. [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/paint/LinearGradient.html)'s the description how it works.  Instead of filling the shapes with solid colors, it fills them with a gradient pattern. Then it's just a matter of combining multiple shapes of various sizes and patterns.

If you want to get exactly the same colors, you'll probably need to read their rgb values and define them just like I did:

```
Color.rgb(225, 229, 111)
```

Here's my try. It's not perfect, but it *somewhat* resembles what you're trying to achieve. Fiddle with colors and sizes and you'll get the desired result, and instead of giving absolute values you can parametrize some things, for example the size of the shadow, or space between the square and the inner circle, and so on.

```
public class JavaFXTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(300,100);
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

        Stop[] stops;
        LinearGradient gradient;

        // outer circle
        stops = new Stop[]{new Stop(0, Color.LIGHTSKYBLUE), new Stop(1, Color.BLUE)};
        gradient = new LinearGradient(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, true, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE, stops);
        gc.setFill(gradient);
        gc.fillOval(10, 14, 40, 40);
        gc.fill();
        gc.stroke();

        // Inner circle
        stops = new Stop[]{new Stop(0, Color.BLUE), new Stop(1, Color.LIGHTSKYBLUE)};
        gradient = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 1, 1, true, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE, stops);
        gc.setFill(gradient);
        gc.fillOval(13, 17, 34, 34);
        gc.fill();
        gc.stroke();

        // Square shadow
        gc.rect(70, 10, 50, 50);
        gc.setFill(Color.GRAY);
        gc.fill();

        // Square
        gc.beginPath();
        gc.setFill(Color.rgb(225, 229, 111));
        gc.rect(70, 10, 48, 48);
        gc.fill();

        // Circle shadow
        gc.beginPath();
        stops = new Stop[]{new Stop(0, Color.GRAY), new Stop(1, Color.WHITE)};
        gradient = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 1, 1, true, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE, stops);
        gc.setFill(gradient);
        gc.fillOval(74, 14, 40, 40);
        gc.fill();
        gc.setStroke(Color.WHITE);

        // Circle
        gc.setFill(Color.rgb(255, 255, 153));
        gc.fillOval(76, 16, 38, 38);
        gc.fill();
        gc.setStroke(Color.WHITE);
        gc.stroke();

        root.getChildren().add(canvas);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

And that's the result:

[image: Result]

Comment: thanks Dth, and the square with circle inside, maybe if I use the same example

Comment: it´s possible the the `blue circle` and the `yellow circle` in `square` are the same size

Comment: I've updated my answer and they should be equal now. As I said, things related to the size should be parametrized, because setting it manually every time isn't the right way to do it.

Comment: very nice and that´s all

Comment: It is possible to select the `blue circle`  in `canvas` with `canvas.setOnMouseClicked` and move in **horizontal**  with `canvas.setOnMouseMoved`, without know the `position of blue circle`?

Comment: Not directly, because you can't interact with the figures you draw this way. But you can create a `Circle` object, and use `.setOnMouseDragged` on it to detect movement.